# Equal width and height with a fixed height set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating some tiles and it all fits onto one page, so each tile has a fixed height. In this example I'm wanting to create a grid of 3 rows, where the height of each row is always 33%, and each square would just take this 33% to decide its height. So effectively you could say:

```
height: 33%;
width: height;
```

I've been looking around and I've seen a few ways at doing this using width, but haven't seen anywhere where you have a fixed height.

Any ideas?

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/wL68jwxc/

Here is a fiddle showing my current code. So, after some help below, I would like to make sure that these 2 squares are always on the same row...so if I change the width of the screen, they remain squares and on the same row regardless of screen size. I realise this is quite different to the title, but the logic of the question remains the same.

Comment: How the html looks like?

Comment: submit your html for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with viewport units.

```
div {
  width: 33.33333vh;
  height: 33.33333vh;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 33.33333vh;
  height: 33.33333vh;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I don't know if this will fit his exact need, but mad respect for utilizing vh.

Comment: Well I didn't know you could set `vh` for width too so thanks for that. Do you know how I would make it so that these also respond to the width of page. I basically have 3 rows of 2 squares, I've tried setting a `max-width` of `33vh` but that didn't seem to work. I can deal with the padding and layout etc later on but for the moment I'd like to get 3 rows of 2 squares which always have a height of 33%. With this setting, if I change the width of the page, the squares don't respond and are cut off.

Comment: They can't be square and be related to **both** height and width...it's not logical

Comment: If you want to be responsive to both the width and height of the viewport, use `33.333vmin` ;)